# Whats the difference between flex.sm vs flex.md vs fxFlex.lg and fxFlex.gt-lg and so on?

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox

I do understand the terms it stands for, small, medium, large and grater than large. I have read through https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Responsive-API and https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/ and so on. But I can't understand how sm, md, lg and gt-lg all work together.

For example what does below piece of code mean?

```
<div fxFlex="100" fxFlex.sm="50" fxFlex.md="60" fxFlex.lg="70" fxFlex.gt-lg="80">
```

Answer (score 8):

That line can be broken down like the below:

```
fxFlex="100" - default to 100% width 
fxFlex.sm="50" - on small screens, use 50% width
fxFlex.md="60" - on medium screens, use 60 % width
fxFlex.lg="70" - on Large screens, use 70% width
fxFlex.gt-lg="80" - on Anything greater than a large screen use 80% width
```

Comment: Thanks @Kyle. Does this mean that in extra small screens or screens smaller than small will have width of 100%?

Comment: correct, anything that isn't specified as a different percentage will use 100%.  So for example if fxFlex.gt-lg didn't exist then extra large screens would have a width of 100% as well.